# How big can a mezuzah be?

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, mezuzah, size

I [read in the news](http://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/News.aspx/198320#.VauV_XWlyko) about an Israeli designer, Yaakov Merdinger, who created the world's largest mezuzah case.

[image: The mezuzah -- taller than the door.]

As you can see in the photo, the mezuzah case is bigger than the door.

Is this kosher?

Comment: Mezuzah or mezuzah cover?

Comment: @sam Both, i guess.

Comment: Well halchickly the mezuzah should be placed in the top third of the door post so having the whole mezuzah on the entire door post may be problematic

Comment: On the other hand, if there's a compartment in there at the right position into which a normal *klaf* is placed, the fact that the case is over-sized might not matter.  (The article doesn't say anything about the *klaf*.)

Comment: In the times of the Talmud, they didn't have separate covers affixed to the door post - they literally drilled a hole into the wall at an angle and inserted the scroll. The modern incarnation of an actual "cover" isn't really a halachic issue...

Comment: I suspect the answer is more a matter of proportion to the doorway than an absolute measure of the mezuzah itself.

Comment: At the Kotel there is a large mezuzah cover which is partially transparent so you can see that the klaf inside is equally large. So even though this article is about a mezuzah case, the question of a large klaf still stands. Picture of giant koten mezuzah: https://www.flickr.com/photos/bachrach44/19885274442/in/dateposted-public/

Answer (score 3):

A *mezuzah* case is really only a way to extend the halachik doorpost such that there is no need to actually insert the *klaf* into the doorpost itself, so inherently, size should not be a halachik issue. Even with regard to the *mezuzah klaf* (parchment) itself, as long as it can fit in the appropriate place on the doorpost (bottom of top third, not within the uppermost *tefach* *), there shouldn't be a problem. According to Ashkenazic custom you might also need a rather wide doorpost as well in order to be able to angle it. On the other hand, you would not need as tall a doorpost since the Ashkenazic custom is to place it at shoulder height if the doorway is very tall (see Shach 289:4 based on Yerushalmi; in contrast, see also Yalkut Yosef YD 285:77 who does not rule differently for tall doorways). See: http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Mezuzah:

[image: Tall doorway]

- See *Rashi Menachoth* 33a s.v. “*b'techila*,” *Rambam Hilchoth Mezuzah* 6:12, *Tur* 289, *Shulchan Aruch* 289:2

Answer (score 0):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן יא - הלכות מזוזה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0010_L2) says that a Mezuza must be placed in the upper 3rd of the doorpost, but at least a Tefach (about 8 cm, 3") away from the lintel.

> **סעיף ה':** 
>   מְקוֹמָהּ מִתְּחִלַּת שְׁלִישׁ הָעֶלְיוֹן שֶׁל גֹּבַהּ הַשָּׁעַר. קְבָעָהּ לְמַעְלָה מִזֶּה, כְּשֵׁרָה, וְהוּא שֶׁיַּרְחִיקֶנָּה מִן הַמַּשְׁקוֹף טֶפַח. קְבָעָהּ לְמַטָּה מִשְּׁלִישׁ הָעֶלְיוֹן, צָרִיךְ לַהֲסִירָהּ וּלְקָבְעָהּ כָּרָאוּי וּבִבְרָכָה. וְאִם קְבָעָהּ בְּטֶפַח הָעֶלְיוֹן, יְסִירָה גַּם כֵּן וְיִקְבְּעֶהָ כָּרָאוּי, אֲבָל לֹא יְבָרֵךְ.‏

So if the doorway is high enough, a tall Mezuza can be used. In this case, the doorpost would have to be about 5.70m (over 18 feet) tall. Such doors [do exist, in Cape Canaveral](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090326172601AAXTrbX).

However, the article is misleading, as it's not referring to a Mezuza, but a Mezuza-**case**. How to write a Kosher Mezuza that would be that tall, is unclear to me - unless the Sofer uses very, very large margins on top and below the writing. (A Mezuza is traditionally written on 22 lines; so (without monster margins) you're looking at letters about 4cm - 1.5" tall, since the space between the lines should be the same height as the letters. Try using a 108-point font to see what I'm referring to, then try find a quill or feather large enough to write that.)

[image]

Comment: You don't actually need to use a quill or feather, nor does the writing implement need to make each 'stroke' in one motion. You can outline and fill in at will.

Comment: @DoubleAA, correct, you can. Good luck to the Sofer who plans on spending days (on a ladder) filling in 1.5" letters, without the ability to fix (almost) any leaks and smudges. Of course it can be done; people have even walked on the moon. I'm also wondering where you plan on getting Klaf that tall; though from http://www.knoll.com/product/sabrina-leather-hide I see that 55 sq feet of hide does exist.

Comment: On a ladder? What's stopping you from laying it on the floor and sitting next to it with a paint brush?

Comment: The mezuzah has to be in the upper third, but what if it's *also* in the middle third and the lower third, like would be the case for such a large mezuzah?